# Compressing and Decompress in PHP and JS

Tags: php, encryption, compression

I was wondering if someone has come up with something similar to this??

a way to compress a text:

```
<?php
    $str = 'Hello world!';// the text here can be any characters long
    $key = compress($str);// should return a key 32characters long/ or a fixed number of characters
    $value = decompress($key);// should return "Hello World!"
?>
```

Using MD5 is a one way encryption/compression,
basically I would like something like MD5 to be reversable. Not necessarly the MD5 it self.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

md5 is not a compression algorithm : it's a [hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) algorithm.

If you want to compress/decompress, in PHP, you can use something like [`gzcompress`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzcompress.php), [`gzdeflate`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzdeflate.php), [`bzcompress`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bzcompress.php), ... depending on the compression algorithm you want to use, and the functions available on your server.

You can take a look at the [Compression and Archive Extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/refs.compression.php) section of the manual, which lists the different extensions you might be able to use -- provided they're installed on your server.

Comment: But bear in mind that HTTP will negotiate and compress data on the fly if possible at both ends.

Comment: I agree. Let something like php's ob_gzhandler or even better mod\_deflate handle the compression transparently if possible.